# MySQL 5.6 - select results where the most recent of multiple datetime columns is 1 month ago at least

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

I have a table with multiple datetime columns in a mySQL 5.6 database.

```
email_id
email_sent_date (datetime)
email_replied_date (datetime)
email_bounced_date(datetime)
email_archived (datetime)
```

I want to retrieve all emails where the **latest datetime of the group** (email_sent_date,email_replied_date, email_bounced_date, email_archived) is at least 1 month ago from today.

I would like to do something like this, even though i think I can't use this max(), but you'll get a sense of what I am trying to achieve:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE MAX(email_sent_date,email_replied_date, email_bounced_date, email_archived) <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the function `greatest()`, not `max()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE GREATEST(email_sent_date, email_replied_date, email_bounced_date, email_archive) <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY;
```

Note:  If any of the values are `NULL`, then the row will be filtered out.

I prefer explicit comparisons because I think the logic is easier to follow:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE email_sent_date <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND 
      email_replied_date <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND
      email_bounced_date <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND
      email_archive <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY;
```

EDIT:

Handling `NULL` values requires explicit checks.  Perhaps:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (email_sent_date <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY OR email_sent_date IS NULL) AND 
      (email_replied_date <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY OR email_replied_date IS NULL) AND
      (email_bounced_date  <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY OR email_bounced_date IS NULL) AND
      (email_archive <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY OR email_archive IS NULL);
```

Comment: ho ok feel stupid, not to have found this function. will try it tonight! thanks

Comment: thanks for the comment because actually any of them can be null, sometimes multiple are null